# How to convert date time to timestamp, add 6 hours and convert it back to date time in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

how to **add 6 hours** to this string?

**$parent = "2011-08-04 15:00:01";**

I think the best way is to convert it to timestamp add 21600 seconds and then convert it back to date time.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're maybe looking for the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php function

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2011-08-04 15:00:01");
$timestamp += 6 * 3600;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sixhours_from_parent = strtotime($parent) + 21600;
$sixhours_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sixhours_from_parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$parent = "2011-08-04 15:00:01";
$parentTime = strtotime($parent);
$later = strtotime("+6 hours", $parentTime);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $later);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `timestamp`/`datetime` value from SQL. You can use for it

```
SELECT datefield + INTERVAL 6 HOUR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($parent) + 21600);
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP > 5.3 you can use the *DateInterval* class on a *DateTime* object, which I think is the easiest way to deal with the complexity of time calculations. So in your case you could do something like this:

```
$time = new \DateTime("2011-08-04 15:00:01");
$time->add(new \DateInterval('PT6H')); //add six hours
echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)