# Add hours to datetime in PHP

Tags: php

I got a variable named `$transactiontime`. I want to add 6 hours to that variable. But I need to exclude the time between 12.00AM and 6.00AM.

For example,
I made a transaction at `1/1/2016 11.00PM`. After adding 6 hours, the output should be `2/1/2016 11.00AM`.

How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: You should check this answer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942733/how-to-convert-date-time-to-timestamp-add-6-hours-and-convert-it-back-to-date-t

Comment: Add 6 hours. If then the result is inside that exclusion zone, add another 6 (the length of the inclusion zone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` is an awesome feature in PHP

```
$string = '1/1/2016 11.00PM';

$date = new DateTime($string);
$interval = new DateInterval('PT6H');
$date->add($interval);

// Now add another 6 hours while we are between 12:00 AM and 6:00 AM
while($date->format('G') >= 0 && $date->format('G') <= 6)
{
    $date->add($interval);    
}

echo $date->format('H:i:s M-j-Y');
```

This outputs the desired

```
11:00:00 Jan-2-2016
```

***Update***

After our extensive [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104803/discussion-between-nordenheim-and-redzwan-latif) about the logic of this particular piece of code, we came to the conclusion, that any transaction done between *midnight* and *6:00 AM* should add 6 hours starting from *6:00 AM* (so, basically, set it to *midday*).

And every other transaction adds 6 hours normally. But if after adding those 6 hours the time interval falls between *midnight* and *6:00 AM*, only the respective amount of time between the *initial* and *midnight* and the rest should be added to *6:00 AM*, which is, ***basically*** is adding just 12 hours to the initial value.

So here's the modified code:

```
$date = new DateTime($string);
$interval = new DateInterval('PT6H');

if($date->format('G') >= 0 && $date->format('G') <= 6)
{
    $date->setTime(12,0,0);
}
else
{
    $date->add($interval);
    if($date->format('G') >= 0 && $date->format('G') <= 6)
    {
        $date->add($interval);
    }
}

echo $date->format('H:i:s M-j-Y');
```

**Example #1**

```
// input
$string = '1/1/2016 3.00AM';

//output
12:00:00 Jan-1-2016 // this is midday
```

**Example #2**

```
// input
$string = '1/1/2016 11.00AM';

//output
17:00:00 Jan-1-2016 // this is 5:00 PM
```

**Example #3**

```
// input
$string = '1/1/2016 11.00PM';

//output
11:00:00 Jan-2-2016 // this is 11:00 AM
```

Comment: Thanks ! I assume that 12.00AM - 6.00AM is exluded?

Comment: @RedzwanLatif that is why `while($date->format('G') >= 0 && $date->format('G') <= 6)` is there

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: It seems that if I do transactions at 2.00AM it does not add correctly. When I do transaction at 2.00AM, it should add 6 hours to 6.00AM. Is there anyway I can solve this?

Comment: @RedzwanLatif Let's get clear on terminology here. You wanted to **add** 6 hours to the initial datetime and **add another** 6 hours in case the time falls into the interval between midnight and 6 AM, right? So of course, if the datetime is 2 AM, you get another 6 hours added, to a total of 8 AM. Or am I missing it?

Comment: For example, lets say that I make a transaction at 11.00PM, the output should be 11.00AM. If I make a transaction at 3.00PM, the output should be 9.00PM. It just excludes the time between 12 midnight and 6.00AM

Comment: You have just posted two mutually exclusive comments. My code in the answer checks the time and if it falls between midnight and 6:00 AM, it adds 6 more hours. So if the time gets 2:00 AM, 6 hours will be added to a total of 8:00 AM. I do not understand why you want it to be 6:00 AM as you stated in the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description, it's just like this, everytime I make the transaction, it should add 6 hours to the $transactiontime but it needs to exclude the time between 12.00 midnight and 6.00AM. so if a transaction is made at 2.00AM, it should start adding 6 hours at 6.00AM.

Comment: You did it again - another mutually exclusive comment :) No worries. Look, you just said that you make a transaction at *11:00 PM* and that the output should be *11:00 AM*, but *11:00 PM* plus 6 hours gives *5:00 AM* plus another 6 hours it gives *11:00 AM*. But now you say that if time after adding the first 6 hours is between *midnight* and *6:00 AM*, the adding should start at *6:00 AM*. That means that *11:00 PM* plus 6 hours equals *5:00 AM*, then go to *6:00 AM* and add another 6 hours, which must be *midday*. So what exactly is it?

Comment: Sorry again :(. Actually, there should be no transaction between 12 midnight and 6.00AM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104803/discussion-between-nordenheim-and-redzwan-latif).